# ClassNotFoundException: javax.jws.WebService

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I'm trying to deploy a simple java servlet to Tomcat, one that consumes a web-service which is deployed to same Tomcat on localhost. I'm working with a Maven project in Netbeans.

The servlet imports the following classes:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceRef;
```

I'm able to deploy the generated war file to Tomcat, but i fail to start the application with the following errors in catalina.out:

```
    28-Mar-2020 20:57:12.769 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-93] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error deploying web application archive [/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.31/webapps/CalculatorWebServiceClient.war]
                        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child
                                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:720)
                                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
                                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
                                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:978)
                                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:493)
                                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1642)
                                at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor66.invoke(Unknown Source)
                                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                                at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
                                at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:289)
                                at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:809)
                                at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
                                at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1590)
                                at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.upload(HTMLManagerServlet.java:294)
                                at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:212)
                                at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
                                at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
                ...
                  Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/CalculatorWebServiceClient]]
                                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
                                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
                                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
                                ... 43 more
                        Caused by: java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type javax.jws.WebService not present
                                at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy.generateException(TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy.java:46)
                                at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationInvocationHandler.invoke(AnnotationInvocationHandler.java:86)
                                at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.value(Unknown Source)
                                at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processServletContainerInitializers(ContextConfig.java:1699)
                                at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1137)
                                at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:774)
                                at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:301)
                                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
                                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5051)
                                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
                                ... 44 more
                        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.jws.WebService
                                at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1365)
                                at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1188)
                                at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
                                at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
                                at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:114)
```

I have noticed the *ClassNotFoundException: javax.jws.WebService* in the log file and edited the pom.xml file to include:

`javax.xml.ws.jaxws-api.2.3.1` and also its compile dependencies as found per [https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.ws/jaxws-api/2.3.1/][1]:

```
javax.annotation.javax.annotation-api.1.3.2
javax.xml.bind.jaxb-api.2.3.1
javax.xml.soap.javax.xml.soap-api.1.4.0
```

When inspecting the project directory i can see that the correspondig libraries are present in WEB-INF/lib directory.

Even after this I keep getting the same error message and cannot start the application.
Could somebody tell me what i'm missing here?

Kind regards,
Michal

Comment: were you able to solve this? i'm having the same problem

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and changed in IDE used Java version from 11 to 8, plus set my Maven to 3.3.9 and "ClassNotFoundException: javax.jws.WebService" problem was solved for me.

Answer (score 1):

This JAR solved similar issue for me.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.jws</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.jws-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using java 11 then you must receive this erorr as no more JAXB(  javax.xml.bind does not exist any more in java 11)

Add below dependencies in your pom file to resolve this.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hus Mukh - Tried this but still facing the same issue. Is there any additional dependency that needs to be injected or any additional configuration that you did?